# NullPointerException error when calling a Method with openFileInput from a different class

Tags: android, class, methods, nullpointerexception

New to android programming - apologies for incorrect jargon.

My app can save data entered to `EditText` fields.
It then can load this data and set the values of this data to String Variables.
Then it preforms a POST HTTP request with these strings.

I'm loading/saving string files using `openFileInput` and `openFileOutput`

I've created Methods:

```
public String LoadMethod()
public String SaveMethod()
```

*These Methods work fine when the Method is in same class as the Activity calling it.*

My problem is that 2 Activities need to be able to run the `public String LoadMethod()`

So what i did was create 2 java class files for Loading and Saving data.
Some commenting is in the files as I've been trying to debug.

LoadUserDetails.java

```
public class LoadUserDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String sSavedName;
    public static String sSavedCompany;
    public static String sSavedPhone;
    public static String sSavedCarRegistration;
    String sNameFile = "name_file";
    //private Context context;

    public String LoadMethod(){

    /* OPEN DETAILS FROM INTERNAL STORAGE*/

        //context = getActivity();
        /*NAME*/
        try {

            String sOpenName;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("name_file");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReaderName = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReaderName = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReaderName);
            StringBuffer stringBufferName = new StringBuffer();
            while ((sOpenName = bufferedReaderName.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBufferName.append(sOpenName + "\n");
            }

            sSavedName = (stringBufferName.toString());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code repeats for opening the other 3 string files.

I Launch this method from my `UserDetails.java` Activity and `MainActivity.java` Activity using this code:

```
//Load User Details
        LoadUserDetails load = new LoadUserDetails();
        load.LoadMethod();
```

This is the error I get in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.visitorrego.oem.smartsigninvisitor/com.visitorrego.oem.smartsigninvisitor.UserDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

..........

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:191)
            at com.visitorrego.oem.smartsigninvisitor.LoadUserDetails.LoadMethod(LoadUserDetails.java:31)
            at com.visitorrego.oem.smartsigninvisitor.UserDetails.onCreate(UserDetails.java:37)
```

I've tried using `Context` and the `ContextWrapper` error disappears but i still get the others :(

I know its something to do with calling a method using OpenFileInput from a different class.
I don't have an issue with calling the postrequest method in my webrequest class...

Any ideas?

Can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand from your code, the class LoadUserDetails is not an activity,
so probably you might need to change the

```
public class LoadUserDetails extends AppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class LoadUserDetails
```

Send The Context as parameter from the page you're calling. Because the context is initialized normally onCreate() (usually for activities).

the function will be

```
public String LoadMethod(Context context){
    ....
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput("name_file");
    ....
}
```

and you can call it by

```
 LoadUserDetails load = new LoadUserDetails();
 load.LoadMethod(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks! I've been jumping the gun and don't understand what having extends AppCompatActivity and Context means :P makes more sense now, i knew it would be simple fix like that :D